# sorting array of names in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of people's names:

```
Array
(
    [1] => A. Aitken
    [2] => A. C. Skinner
    [3] => A. Chen
    [4] => R. Baxter
)
```

What's the quickest way to sort the array in (alphabetical) order of the surname in php? i.e. to give

```
Array
(
    [1] => A. Aitken
    [4] => R. Baxter
    [3] => A. Chen
    [2] => A. C. Skinner
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [uksort](http://php.net/uksort) and the example given there, which is very similar to your problem.

You may want to replace the regexps there with

```
preg_replace("/[A-Z]\\. /", '', $a);
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. For completeness you might just want to correct the typo in the pattern - I think it should be "@[A-Z]\\. @" (or "/[A-Z]\\. /").

Answer (score 5):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a1 = explode(' ', $a);
    $b1 = explode(' ', $b);
    return strcasecmp(end($a1), end($b1));
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort using decorate-sort-undecorate pattern by key being last element of array that is result of splitting your string with spaces

```
$arr = array(                                                                                                                                               
'A. Aitken',                                                                                                                                               
'A. C. Skinner',                                                                                                                                           
'A. Chen',                                                                                                                                                 
'R. Baxter'                                                                                                                                                
);                                                                                                                                                          

// actual sorting below                                                                                                                                     
$arr= array_map(create_function('$a', 'return array(array_slice(explode(" ", $a), -1), $a);'), $arr); // transform into array of arrays consisted of sort key and item  
sort($arr); // sort array of arrays                                                                                                                         
$arr = array_map('end', $arr); // take only last element from each array                                                                                    

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: That gives a lot of `E_STRICT` warnings.

Comment: @Daniel Egeberg - thanks, I've fixed this by replacing end() with array_slice(,-1);